# return 0 on sql query instead of nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I return a row showing 0 responses?  This query returns 3 of the 4 ids and the number of responses, but Id 3 is not showing up because it has 0 responses.  I would like for it to show up with 0.

```
SELECT Count(sr.id) AS 'Responses', 
       qpa.possibleanswertext, 
       qpa.id 
FROM   caresplusparticipantsurvey.questionpossibleanswer AS qpa 
       JOIN caresplusparticipantsurvey.surveyresponse AS sr 
         ON qpa.id = sr.questionpossibleanswerid 
WHERE  ( qpa.id BETWEEN 1 AND 4 ) 
       AND ( sr.surveyid IN (SELECT surveyid 
                             FROM   caresplusparticipantsurvey.surveyresponse AS 
                                    sr 
                             WHERE  sr.questionpossibleanswerid = 138) ) 
GROUP  BY qpa.possibleanswertext, 
          qpa.id
```

---

```
    99  Very Useful                                         1
    26  Somewhat useful                                         2
    33  I did not complete this CORE requirement this year  4
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your `join` to a [`left join`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join), which will use `NULL` for rows that don't match:

```
left join CaresPlusParticipantSurvey.SurveyResponse ...
```

You will also need to move your filter to the `ON` section, so remove this:

```
and (sr.SurveyId in (select SurveyId from CaresPlusParticipantSurvey.SurveyResponse as       sr where sr.QuestionPossibleAnswerId = 138))
```

And change your join to this:

```
left join CaresPlusParticipantSurvey.SurveyResponse AS sr 
    ON qpa.id = sr.questionpossibleanswerid
    AND sr.SurveyId IS NULL OR sr.SurveyId in (
        select SurveyId
        from CaresPlusParticipantSurvey.SurveyResponse as sr
        where sr.QuestionPossibleAnswerId = 138
    )
```

Comment: @user1202606: In addition to changing the join type, move the condition on `sr.SurveyId` from the `where` clause to the `on` clause

Comment: Oh yeah, @Andomar's suggestion to use the ON clause is better that mine about changing the WHERE.

Comment: @BrendanLong: A left join is definitely better than my answer :)

Comment: Good Answer. Just out of curiosity, what's the reason for sr.QuestionPossibleAnswerId = 138?

Answer (score 0):

```
; with  CTE as
        (
        ... your query here ...
        )
select  *
from    CTE
union all
select  0
,       null
,       null
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    CTE
        )
```

Comment: your idea in the comments above worked.  Can you edit this to show change to an on clause so I can accept this?  Thanks again

Comment: @user1202606: My comment was just a small addition to Brendan Long's answer, so by all means accept his answer.